# What should I do while I'm waiting for the build / the tests / the database migrations to run?

Tags: testing, build, focus

As best-behaved as I try to be about keeping my unit tests disconnected from the database, etc. etc, it still seems inevitable that my day will be interrupted by small regular enforced breaks while I wait for my machine to do something boring.

[image: xkcd comic: compiling]

I personally find swordfighting makes me lose my train of thought. I'm often 'in the zone' when I run a build or suite of tests, and I'd prefer something that keeps me in the same focussed frame of mind, jumping me right back to hacking as soon as the build / test run / migration is done.

I used to fantasize about a Tetris plugin for Visual Studio that popped up during the build and then paused and disappeared automatically when the build completed, but I never actually did anything about it. Lately we were thinking about building something into [autotest](http://www.zenspider.com/) which helps you learn Spanish while you wait for the tests to run, or maybe feeds you relevant stack overflow questions to answer.

So. Suggestions please. Points for fun yet rewarding activities.

Comment: This should be a community-wiki question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. StackOverflow
2. Coffee
3. StackOverflow
4. Side project coding

See also [How to keep concentrated and focused while waiting for your compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922/how-to-keep-concentrated-and-focused-while-waiting-for-your-compiler)

Comment: Man! Have you already built that stackoverflow feed? You answered the question in a matter of seconds. Have a point for promptness!

Comment: Just er... timing...yeah, that's it... just a coincidence...

Comment: sadly the linked question was deleted, maybe someone could sum up the content ?

Answer (score 4):

I normally use this time to read blogs ant to check the bug list, to see if there is something pending that I forgot to do.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally?

- Write up notes on the fixes/feature added. (Notebooks are GREAT when two years from now you need to decipher something you did.)
- Read something that pertains to your work.
- Check for other small errata and bugs.
- Document (for other people) your feature/code.

Realisticly:

- Stackoverflow
- Slashdot
- Lifehacker
- Blogs

Answer (score 2):

Use the time for ordering a **new, much faster** developer machine / server.

Answer (score 1):

Coffee, Chitchat, StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I usually read blogs, articles, mostly work related.
I have dedicated time to read everything not work related (30 minutes time-frame after lunch).

 I also find myself going through our websites to see if I find a bug or something that can be improved.

 And on a Friday (like today:) ) I read Freak Angels:) Warren Ellis on-line free comic. The man is on a rampage on that one:) 
Check it out:http://www.freakangels.com/?p=23

Comment: How exactly is this going to help me stay focused?! ;)

Comment: Well, I stay focused by doing things that get my mind off what I'm working on. Different people, different choices:)